# Cert-Manager does not start CertificateRequest and Certificate process with Ingress annotation (Traefik + Letsencrypt)

Tags: kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager, traefik-ingress

I am trying to secure some internal applications using cert-manager with traefik as the Ingress controller.

From what I understood from both Traefik and Cert-Manager documentation, the process consist in installing both, creating an Issuer (I am trying now to create a ClusterIssuer for simplicity) and then assign such issuer to the ingress rule using an annotation.

As far as I can see there are no errors on the logs neither in cert-manager or traeffik, and the issuer is installed (against letsencrypt staging) and the letsencrypt account succesfully created, nevertheless when I create the ingress rule nothing happens, I see no certificaterequest or certificate resource being created, no errors on the logs and no problems on the "kubectl describe" of the existing resources.

I have installed cert-manager using the "default install" method:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.12.0/cert-manager.yaml
```

Traefik was installed already on the k3s cluster I am using. This resulted in Traefik installed in the kube-system NS while cert-manager is its default cert-manager NS.

The configuration seems pretty straighforward, just changing the default issuer for a ClusterIssuer:

```
❯ cat issuer-letsencrypt-stagging.yaml 
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: EDITED
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: carles-cc-account-key
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: traefik
```

```
❯ cat ingress-miniflux.yaml 
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert.manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
  name: miniflux-ingress
  namespace: miniflux
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rss.EDITED
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: miniflux-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - rss.carles.cc
    secretName: tls-miniflux-ingress-http
```

Both objects seem to be created fine, at least from what I can see with my little experience:

```
❯ k describe clusterissuers.cert-manager.io letsencrypt-staging 
Name:         letsencrypt-staging
Namespace:    
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         ClusterIssuer
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-07-14T23:34:07Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:acme:
          .:
          f:email:
          f:privateKeySecretRef:
            .:
            f:name:
          f:server:
          f:solvers:
    Manager:      kubectl-create
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2023-07-14T23:34:07Z
    API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:acme:
          .:
          f:lastPrivateKeyHash:
          f:lastRegisteredEmail:
          f:uri:
        f:conditions:
          .:
          k:{"type":"Ready"}:
            .:
            f:lastTransitionTime:
            f:message:
            f:observedGeneration:
            f:reason:
            f:status:
            f:type:
    Manager:         cert-manager-clusterissuers
    Operation:       Update
    Subresource:     status
    Time:            2023-07-14T23:34:08Z
  Resource Version:  1993510
  UID:               b728c933-150f-4a08-b00a-b52409a54121
Spec:
  Acme:
    Email:            EDITED
    Preferred Chain:  
    Private Key Secret Ref:
      Name:  carles-cc-account-key
    Server:  https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    Solvers:
      http01:
        Ingress:
          Class:  traefik
Status:
  Acme:
    Last Private Key Hash:  pfe/BG8+dbdU79nq0sYvfg8wgkm0nD8Ig/Up4FbxjGM=
    Last Registered Email:  EDITED
    Uri:                    https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/110964394
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-07-14T23:34:08Z
    Message:               The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                ACMEAccountRegistered
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Ready
Events:                    <none>
```

But no events are generated, no erros on logs on the cert-manager, and the certificate/secrets/orders are not generated, just nothing happens in a way that gives me any clue of what's wrong:

```
 k describe -n miniflux ingress miniflux-ingress 
Name:             miniflux-ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        miniflux
Address:          10.9.8.13
Ingress Class:    traefik
Default backend:  <default>
TLS:
  tls-miniflux-ingress-http terminates rss.carles.cc
Rules:
  Host           Path  Backends
  ----           ----  --------
  rss.carles.cc  
                 /   miniflux-svc:80 (10.42.0.221:8080)
Annotations:     cert.manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
Events:          <none>
```

```
k get certificaterequests.cert-manager.io -A
No resources found
```

```
❯ k get certificates.cert-manager.io -A
No resources found
```

Any help would be really appreciated, I would love to be able to debug this issue.

Thanks in advance !

Carles

I tried to explain to explain the problem I am facing clearly hoping that someone can help me.

Comment: Delete the secret you defined in your ingress (you named it tls-miniflux-ingress-http), if it exists.  This will force cert-manger to attempt to renew or recreate the certificate.  
You can use https://crt.sh/ to see requests to letsencrypt, although there seems to be a day or two delay.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `cluster-issuer` annotation on your Ingress, there is a typo: It should be `cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer` instead of `cert.manager...` (`-` instead of `.`).